# Evaluate the summation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{\sinh^2 (a n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would you calculate the summation
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{\sinh^2 (a n)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6a^3}, \qquad a>0
$$
EDIT: A litte more background if necessary. I saw this when computing the specific heat of a bosonic system. More specifically,
$$
C_V = \frac{d}{dT} \sum_{k\ne 0} \epsilon_k f_B (\epsilon_k), \quad k \in \frac{2\pi}{L} \mathbb{Z}
$$
where $\epsilon_k=v|k|$ is the energy and$f_B$ is the Bose-Einstein distribution
$$
f_B (\epsilon) = \frac{1}{\exp{(\epsilon/T)}-1}
$$
However, the textbook doesn't show the derivation in detail, especially the evaluation of the infinite summation

EDIT 2: I realized that the answer in the textbook was obtained by taking $L\rightarrow \infty$ so that the summation becomes a Bose-Einstein integral. The discrete infinite summation itself is INCORRECT.

Comment: The answer is false as I checked that when $a=1$, LHS is approximately $1.145$ while RHS is approximately $1.644$. (btw I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: I guess the correct statement is that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{\sinh^2(an)} = (1+o(1))\frac{\pi^2}{6a^3}\qquad\text{as } a \to 0^+.$$This can be proved by realizing the limit of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^3n^2}{\sinh^2(an)}$ as the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{\sinh^2 x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \zeta(2)$.